# How to get all projections by a type with Spring Data REST

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

Is there a way to get all projections by an appropriate type?

I've got a class with several projections. I would like to get a `Map<String, Class<?>>` where

- a `String` is a name of the projection
- a `Class<?>` is a class over which this annotation is

An example:

```
class A { ... }

@Projection(name = "a1", types = A.class)
interface ProjectionA1 { ... }

@Projection(name = "a2", types = A.class)
interface ProjectionA2 { ... }
```

A result might be:

```
-> A.class  
<- ImmutableMap.of("a1", ProjectionA1.class, "a2", ProjectionA2.class);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at: [`RepositoryRestConfiguration`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/core/config/RepositoryRestConfiguration.html)

There you can get the [`ProjectionDefinitionConfiguration`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/core/config/ProjectionDefinitionConfiguration.html) and your desired results via [`ProjectionDefinitionConfiguration::getProjectionsFor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/core/config/ProjectionDefinitionConfiguration.html#getProjectionsFor-java.lang.Class-).

Comment: thank you, the `getProjectionType` returns a desired `Map<String, Class<?>>`

Comment: Just to make it a bit more explicit: 1) declare a field like `@AutoWired RepositoryRestConfiguration repositoryRestConfiguration;`; 2) call in a method like this `repositoryRestConfiguration.getProjectionConfiguration().getProjectionsFor(entityClass)`, where `entityClass` is the class of the entity that have the associated projection you're interested in.